# How to loop for as many times as there are rows in SQL result

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Person object, which has a list of Reports.

```
public class Person
{
    public string IdNum { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Int32 LocFlag { get; set; }
    public IList<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public long ReportNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReceivedDate { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

In my data layer, I want to use 2 SQL Queries to create the Person objects and add them to a list. The point where I'm stuck is - how to loop for only as many times as there are rows in the SQL result for SQL 1.

Each row should be saved as a new Person object and added to the list.

```
 List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
 //SQL 1 - loop as many times as there are results, each loop adding a new Person to list

{
     personList.Add(_context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>(
                    @"SELECT id_txt AS IdNum
                , lastname_txt AS LastName
                , LOCATION_FLG AS LocFlag
                FROM fn_PersonList(@locationId)",
                    new SqlParameter("@locId", locID)
                    ).Single());
 }

 // second sql query to add Report list to the already created Person list

     foreach (Person t in personList)
     {
        i++;
        personList[i].Reports.Insert(i,
        _context.Database.SqlQuery<Report>(
        @"SELECT ID_NUM
            ,  RECEIVED_DTE
            , SUBJECT_TXT                                           
            FROM  fn_Work_Person(@pdNumber, t)  
            WHERE LocID =  & locationID  
            ORDER BY ID_NUM DESC",
            new SqlParameter("@locationId", locationID)).Single());
    }
    return personList;
```

Comment: What is the return type of `_context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>()` ?  Is it `List<Person>` or `IEnumerable<Person>`?  If so could you just do `personList = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>(...).ToList()`?

Comment: ToList was the answer! Thank you Quan

Comment: Also you can try to use personList.AddRange(... without  ToList().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
personList = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>(
                @"SELECT id_txt AS IdNum
            , lastname_txt AS LastName
            , LOCATION_FLG AS LocFlag
            FROM fn_PersonList(@locationId)",
                new SqlParameter("@locId", locID)
                ).ToList();
```

SqlQuery is probably returning `IEnumerable<Person>` and just needs to be converted to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You may utilize @@Rowcount after the SQL1 to get number of rows or, create an Autonumber field in table (I will call it c_Serial) and get it through "output inserted.c_Serial", just after the FROM clause. You will get the number of registers selected in both cases.

```
            @"SELECT id_txt AS IdNum
            , lastname_txt AS LastName
            , LOCATION_FLG AS LocFlag
            FROM fn_PersonList(@locationId) output inserted.c_serial",
                new SqlParameter("@locId", locID)
                ).Single());
```

or (I will use the SQL syntax since it´s clear to me)

```
            Declare Counter int

            SELECT id_txt AS IdNum
            , lastname_txt AS LastName
            , LOCATION_FLG AS LocFlag
            FROM fn_PersonList(@locationId)

           set @Counter=@@Rowcount
```

Good luck